# html button and href not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code I have an href and a button that uses javascript to post to a new page. The href works when I click it but the button that uses javascript takes several clicks and works intermittently. Some times only three clicks but can be as high as 19 clicks depending on how hard I click the mouse :)

Any ideas why these are behaving differently?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            window.location.href = 'tournaments.aspx';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div style="width:400px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid black;" align="center" >
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="ctl02" src="Images/Advertisement.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="ctl03" src="Images/ISETLogo.png" />
    </div>
    <div >
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
        <a href="tournaments.aspx">tournaments</a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Visually I can not see where the error is. Have you tried commenting out the window.location.href line and just try a simple js alert.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpyPR/7/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably because you have a single button in a `<form>` tag, which will by default try and submit the form when clicked. So in addition to trying to load 'tournaments.aspx' in the current window, you're also POSTing to the current page which will react by reloading.

To prevent this default behaviour, add `return false;` within your `onclick`:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            window.location.href = 'tournaments.aspx';           
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div style="width:400px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid black;" align="center" >
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="ctl02" src="Images/Advertisement.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="ctl03" src="Images/ISETLogo.png" />
    </div>
    <div >
        <button onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Click me</button>
        <a href="tournaments.aspx">tournaments</a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Add return false where? Ah I see. Still you should include it for noobs like me :)

Comment: Look at my example - it's immediately after your call to `myFunction()` in the `onclick` of the button.